# How to check if a term contains variable?

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to prolog. I am trying to implement the predicate `occurs(Variable, Term)` that succeeds if the prolog variable Variable
occurs in the prolog term Term, and fails otherwise.

```
occurs(Variable,Term) :-
    Term =.. List.
occurs(Variable, List).
occurs(Variable,[_|L]) :- 
    occurs(Variable,L).
```

I tried converting Term into list and then comparing, it always returns true.

any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's can be done by calling the goal `ground/1` which checks if some predicate doesn't contain vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `occurs/2` check will succeed, regardless what the term is, since you wrote a `occurs(Variable, List).` fact that will satisfy all values.

Basically there are two cases we need to consider:

1. the term is a variable, and that variable is equal to the one we are querying; and
2. the term is a functor, and one of the arguments contains that variable.

We thus can implement this as:

```
occurs(Variable, Variable) :-
    var(Variable).
occurs(Variable, Term) :-
    \+ var(Term),
    Term =.. [_|Args],
    occurring(Args, Variable).

occurring([H|_], Variable) :-
    occurs(Variable, H).
occurring([_|T], Variable) :-
    occurring(T, Variable).
```

We can however make use of [**`term_variables/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_variables/2), and thus perform a [**`member/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) to enumerate over the list:

```
occurs(Variable, Term) :-
    term_variables(Term, Vars),
    member(Variable, Vars).
```

Comment: That `member/2` never checks, as it always succeeds. A checking implementation would fail sometimes

Comment: @false: I think the idea is that you can query `dif(X, Y), occurs(X, a(X, Y))`. So it will trigger the `dif/2`, but that is indeed more due to the `dif`, not the `member`.

Comment: If you are interested in variables, `occurs(Vi, T), Vi == V` would be a more common test (using your definition).